# trying to clear _PAGE_PRESENT bit and encountered kernel panic

Tags: linux-kernel

Being new to kernel programming, I am trying to get my hands dirty with kernel code. I am trying to clear PAGE_PRESENT bit of a pte (page table entry)

So, I do the following

```
    temp_pte = pte_clear_flags(pte, _PAGE_PRESENT);
    set_pte(ptep, temp_pte);
```

But I am encountering a kernel crash. The trace is at the following link
http://pastebin.com/5MZ3xzd3

These were few fishy lines I could identify from the logs:

Jun  6 16:43:44 lenovo-laptop kernel: [  131.834145] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at fffa6120

Jun  6 16:43:44 lenovo-laptop kernel: [  131.835065] IP: [] native_set_pte+0x3/0x10

Jun  6 16:43:44 lenovo-laptop kernel: [  131.835598] *pde = 018c7067 *pte = 00000000

20060                           /Base Board Product Name
Jun  6 16:43:44 lenovo-laptop kernel: [  131.842637] EIP: 0060:[] EFLAGS: 00010282 CPU: 1

Jun  6 16:43:44 lenovo-laptop kernel: [  131.843372] EIP is at native_set_pte+0x3/0x10

I went through the following Stack overflow link as the logs were little similar, but still could not understand why is it happening.

[What do these Linux Kernel Oops fields mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193873/what-do-these-linux-kernel-oops-fields-mean)

Is it that I need to take some locks before calling set_pte? I looked at the usage of this function at various places and I tried to use it the same way. Why is it that a kernel paging request happening, because if you look inside the set_pte function, I did not find any allocations happening there but mmu ops are being called.

Any pointers or help would be great as I am stuck on this. Thanks

Comment: Post your code. Problem must be with your module

Comment: Thanks for your time! Here is the code http://pastebin.com/QVSZNZua If set_pte is commented, everything is fine. Else there is kernel panic.

Comment: I thought the error could be due to one of the following - locks, wrong set of functions being used or not clearing pte before setting it. I manipulated the code to check these, but still the same kernel panic, not sure what is going wrong. I tried using pte_clear before setting pte
 pte_clear(mm, address, ptep);
        //set_pte(ptep, temp_pte);
Also since there is a choice for functions, like for eg., set_pte and set_pte_at etc., I am not sure if I am using the wrong set.

Comment: Its my bad. The problem was happening because of a write lock that was supposed to be taken on task's mm. After taking it, the panic is resolved.